# Django admin export statistics based on model

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm new in Django and I encountered problem in my project. I'm using Django-Import-Export module to export data from admin panel to csv, xls etc. My project contains class of statistics which fields are the result of the query to other class. The statistics class is created by models.Manager where I returned specified queryset.

I see statistics in my admin panel but when I try to export them I get blank fields with only column names.
I made a resource class for statistics class and specified the resource class in admin. What I need to do to export such data, not from datebase table?

Comment: Maybe I need to specify what data I want to export in overridden before_export method in my model resource class?

Comment: The solution is to override export method in resources class.